# Stranger things in my .tex file

Tags: bibliographies

I have a problem with my `.tex` file that shows "[chapter]" and "(n.d.)." in my text and I do not want to do not this. These words do not appear in my text. The problem appeared after I changed my bibstyle.

[image: Problem]

My .tex looks like this:

```
\documentclass[
article, 
12pt, 
oneside, 
a4paper,,  
english, 
english 
]{abntex2}          

\usepackage{mathtools}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools
\usepackage[brazilian,hyperpageref]{}
\usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite}
\usepackage{times}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{nomencl} % Lista de simbolos
\usepackage{color}  % Controle das cores
\usepackage{graphicx}  % Inclusão de gráficos
\usepackage{subfig}             % Subfiguras com títulos
\usepackage{caption}            % Nota de rodapé - figuras
\captionsetup{format=hang}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\ifpdf%
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\else
\usepackage{lscape}  % Modo paísagem
\fi           
\usepackage{epstopdf}           % Para figuras de alta resolução EPS
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{microtype} 
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
% para melhorias de justificação
\usepackage{ctable}             % Suporte para configuração de tabelas - rodapés fixos
\usepackage{longtable}          % Para tabelas em landscape
\usepackage{booktabs}           % Ajustes tabelas
\usepackage{cleveref}           % Referenciar tabelas com ctable package \cref{}
\usepackage{float}              % H - Fixar posição de figura/tabela - evitar flutuação se necessário
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}    % Colorir tabelas
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http
\usepackage{longtable, ltcaption}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{scrlayer}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  rightmargin,
  contents={%
    \parbox[b][\layerheight][c]{\dimexpr\footskip+\footheight\relax}{%
      \hfill\rotatebox{90}{\pagemark}}}
]{lscape.foot}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  textarea,
  addhoffset=\dimexpr-\headsep-\headheight\relax,
  width=\dimexpr\headsep+\headheight\relax,
  contents={\hfill\rotatebox{90}{\headmark}\hspace*{\headsep}}
]{lscape.head}
\DeclareNewPageStyleByLayers{lscape}{lscape.foot,lscape.head}
\usepackage{trivfloat}
\trivfloat{chart} % cria nova lista com nome: ``char''

\usepackage[labelfont=bf,textfont=md]{caption}
\usepackage[format=plain, 
justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}

%--------------------------------------------------------------
% CONFIGURAÇÃO DO PAPER
%--------------------------------------------------------------

% Definição de margens - package geometry
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.50cm]{geometry}

% Recuo do parágrafo :
\setlength{\parindent}{1.25cm}

% Controle do espaçamento entre um parágrafo e outro %  \onelineskip
\setlength{\parskip}{0.0cm}  


% Espaçamento entre linhas
\SingleSpacing
%\OnehalfSpacing

% Informações de autoria PDF e cores de links e citações
% Definir cor de citação
\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{30,50,100}
\hypersetup{
pagebackref=true,
pdftitle={\@title}, 
pdfauthor={\@author},
pdfsubject={Artigo},
pdfcreator={LaTeX},
pdfkeywords={.}{.}, 
colorlinks=true, % false: boxed links; true: colored links
linkcolor=blue,     % color of internal links
citecolor=blue,     % color of links to bibliography
filecolor=magenta,  % color of file links
urlcolor=blue,
bookmarksdepth=4
}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Teorema}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lema}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposição}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corolário}


%\newenvironment{proof}[1][Prova]
\renewcommand\qedsymbol{$\blacksquare$}

% Ajustamento de colunas de tabelas
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%Normas da revista
\renewcommand*\thesection{\textbf{\arabic{section}.}}
\renewcommand*\thesubsection{\textbf{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mathleft}{\@fleqntrue\@mathmargin0pt}
\newcommand{\mathcenter}{\@fleqnfalse}
\makeatother

\usepackage{apacite}
\setkomafont{author}{\scshape}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{manyfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote{A}[alph]
\DeclareNewFootnote{B}[arabic]
\DeclareNewFootnote{C}[fnsymbol]

\usepackage{setspace} % espacamento entre linhas

% padrao 1.5 de espacamento entre linhas
%\setstretch

%--------------------------------------------------------------
% CAPA E/OU FOLHA DE ROSTO
% -------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\section{\textbf{Introduction}}

Something \cite{myers1984six} said

\renewcommand\refname{\textbf{References}}
\bibliography{references.bib}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX and thank you for providing a minimal working example. Still, I wonder: do you really need to load all these packages?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please make your code an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) with the emphasis on _minimal_? You seem to be loading a lot of packages and declaring a lot of options and commands that are not essential to your problem.

Comment: Some bibliography packages use an 'invisible' 'fake' `.bib` entry to pass settings to the `.bst` file. If this 'fake entry' is processed by an incompatible style, you may end up with an empty entry that is just "n.d.". Your preamble is very long, so I can't really tell at the moment whether there is a package that would produce such a fake entry.  The "[chapter]" looks like a preamble command gone wrong, in that case there should be an error in the `.log` file that can hopefully help you identify where the problem comes from.

Comment: Where did you get this template from? There are lots of redundant things.

Comment: If you're using `\usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite}` **don't**` use `\bibliographystyle{apacite}`. why would you want that?

Comment: There are serious problems with your template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplifying your thing:

```
\documentclass[
article, 
12pt, 
oneside, 
a4paper,  
english
]{abntex2}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{Knu86,
    author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
    year = {1986},
    title = {The \TeX book},
  }
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{Knu86,
    author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
    year = {1986},
    title = {The \TeX book},
  }
\end{filecontents*}   


\begin{document}

Something \cite{Knu86} said

\bibliography{\jobname} % if you’re using BibTeX

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As indicated, I made a filter of the packages and there were two of them that were causing the problem: \usepackage{nomencl} \usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite}

Thank you!

Comment: I doubt that it was `nomencl` that was causing the problem, but anyway, there are several packages called twice, you shouldn't use `\textbf` inside a `\section`, etc.